# How could I select an image in a table and then copy it to another td in a diffrent table

Tags: javascript

I'm making a program that generates 2 tables. First has 16 images that represent a menu or options that you can click and then by clicking it you select in. The second table is generated by inputting rows and cells. So the second table is by default blank and each cells is meant to by replaced by an image that you selected in the first table. I've managed to do everything but I don't completley understand how to do the selecting and setting the image. (I assume it has something to do with ids and then onclick()?)

```js
stolpci = window.prompt("vpiši stevilo stolpcov:");
for (i2 = 0; i2 < 1;) {
  if (stolpci < 11 || stolpci > 41) {
    stolpci = window.prompt("Napačno število. Število mora biti večje od 10 in manjše od 40. Ponovno vpiši stevilo stolpcov:");
  } else {
    i2++;
  }
}

vrstice = window.prompt("vpiši stevilo vrstic:");
for (i2 = 0; i2 < 1;) {
  if (vrstice < 6 || vrstice > 11) {
    vrstice = window.prompt("Napačno število. Število mora biti večje od 5 in manjše od 11. Ponovno vpiši stevilo vrstic:");
  } else {
    i2++;
  }
}

function generateTable() {
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");


  for (let i = 0; i < vrstice; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.id = i;
    for (let j = 0; j < stolpci; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      const cellText = document.createTextNode(' ');
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
      cell.id = j;
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

function options() {
  const tbl = document.createElement("table");
  const tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  let nImage = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      const cellText = document.createTextNode("");

      if (nImage > 16) {
        nImage = 1;
      }
      cell.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/sprite" + nImage + ".gif')";
      cell.id = nImage;
      nImage++;

      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}

window.onload = () => {
  options();
  generateTable();
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 32px;
  max-width: 32px;
  max-height: 32px;
  min-height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add click events to each cell. When click you could have another object which you save the 'selected' data to i.e the cell data. You would then need a button which when clicked would move your 'selected' data to the cells in the other table.